# Find $a$ in equation so that it can define a scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine which values for $a$ where

$g(u,v) = u_1v_1 + 5u_2v_2 + au_3v_3+ 2(u_1v_2+u_2v_1)+3(u_1v_3+u_3v_1)+4(u_2v_3+u_3v_2)$

defines a scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I need tips to begin. 
I have tried solving it by setting $g(u,u) \geq 0$

which gives

$u_1^2+5u_2^2+au_3^2+4u_1u_2+6u_1u_3+8u_2u_3\geq 0$

But even in this case $a$ is not solvable.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: This may help: You also must have $g(u, v) = g(v, u)$ for $g$ to be a (real) scalar product.

Comment: @tylerc0816 Very true, though in this case that's trivial - the expression is symmetric in its two arguments.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So I suppose the only thing left is to use the bilinearity of the inner product?

Comment: @tylerc0816 Bilinearity also comes for free here - though you can sort of use it to simplify the positivity constraint.

Comment: You've mistyped the $u_1^2$ as $u_1$ I think; if you correct that and look at turning it into something like $(u_1+u_2)^2 + (u_2+bu_3)^2 + (u_2+cu_3)^2$, which is necessarily positive, you can probably work some value of $a$ out from that.  I'm a bit rushed right now so I haven't time to do it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a brief digression. Let $$B=\begin{bmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}\\b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}\end{bmatrix},$$ and note that $$\begin{align}u^TBv &=[x_1\:x_2\:x_3]\left[\begin{array}{c}b_{11}y_1+b_{12}y_2+b_{13}y_3\\ b_{21}y_1+b_{22}y_2+b_{23}y_3\\ b_{31}y_1+b_{32}y_2+b_{33}y_3\end{array}\right]\\ &= (b_{11}y_1+b_{12}y_2+b_{13}y_3)x_1+(b_{21}y_1+b_{22}y_2+b_{23}y_3)x_2+(b_{31}y_1+b_{32}y_2+b_{33}y_3)x_3\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3b_{ij}x_iy_j\end{align}$$

This gives us a (potentially) more convenient (or at least compact) form in which to write $g.$ Namely, $g(u,v)=u^TBv,$ where $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 5 & 4\\3 & 4 & a\end{bmatrix}.$$

In order for $g$ to represent a scalar product, it is necessary and sufficient that the following be positive:

- $\det[1]$
- $\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2 & 5\end{bmatrix}$
- $\det B$

Comment: We understand this elegant solution and we got that $a$ must be greater than 13. You explanation is far better than one in our book we dont even understand. Just two question: 1.Doest this method apply to all n x n matrices? 2. Can I apply this method if $a$ is in the center of the matrix or if we got many $a$ variables in diffrent locations?

Comment: Given a linear combination $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nb_{ij}x_iy_j,$$ where the $b_{ij}$ are scalars (possibly with one or more indeterminates, like $a$) we can always write rewrite it as $u^TBv,$ where $u=[x_1\:\cdots\:x_n]^T$ and $v=[y_1\:\cdots\:y_n]^T$ and $b_{ij}$ is the $i$th row, $j$th column entry of the $n\times n$ matrix $B$. This represents a scalar product exactly when $B$ is symmetric and its [leading principal minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_minor#Other_applications) have positive determinants. There is no need for the indeterminate(s) to lie on the main diagonal.

Comment: A far better answer than mine to be sure, +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

A wide hint: your $g(u,v)$ can be written as $u^TAv$ (or $\langle u, AV\rangle$) for a suitable matrix $A$.  Find that matrix $A$, and find its eigenvalues (which will be functions of $a$); by diagonalization, your condition for positive semidefiniteness of the product is that all those eigenvalues are $\geq 0$.

Comment: It should be positive definite, rather than semidefinite. And it's not necessary to find the eigenvalues, as principal submatrices suffice.